# Where can I find information about the points awarded for each action on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, reputation

I would like to see a table in the FAQ section of SO detailing the points awarded for each action. Is this possible? Is it available somewhere or this is hidden for a purpose?

Answer (score 2):

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Which is now updated to reflect the recent question upvote rep. change :)

Answer (score 1):

Reopening, because I think the OP's point was valid -- the official /faq should have been improved in this area.

I changed it to be more accurate and up to date, and included a table of ways you can gain and lose rep.

The unofficial faq will always be more detailed, of course, but the /faq should have the essentials and it really didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the reopen and answer

Comment: Not relevant anymore, no more /faq and help center is up to date these days.